# How to install the latest version of Flux.jl?

Tags: julia, flux.jl

I am trying to install the latest version of Flux.jl with Julia 1.6. When I do `add Flux`, it adds version `Flux v0.8.3` but looking at GitHub, it seems the newest release is version `0.12.x`. I have the following packages in my env:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> st
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  [5ae59095] Colors v0.9.6
  [8f4d0f93] Conda v1.5.2
  [7876af07] Example v0.5.3
  [587475ba] Flux v0.8.3
  [7073ff75] IJulia v1.23.2
  [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.0.14
```

I tried removing Flux and re-adding it already. I also tried:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> up Flux
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/General`
    Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git`
    Updating registry at `~/.julia/registries/JuliaPOMDP`
    Updating git-repo `https://github.com/JuliaPOMDP/Registry`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  No Changes to `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Manifest.toml`
```

and I tried adding the specific version I wanted:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> add Flux@v0.12.4
   Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CodecZlib [944b1d66]:
 CodecZlib [944b1d66] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.4.4-0.7.0 or uninstalled
 ├─restricted by compatibility requirements with StackOverflow [1a8df32f] to versions: 0.6.0
 │ └─StackOverflow [1a8df32f] log:
 │   ├─possible versions are: 0.1.0-0.1.2 or uninstalled
 │   └─restricted to versions * by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.1.0-0.1.2
 └─restricted by compatibility requirements with Flux [587475ba] to versions: 0.7.0 — no versions left
   └─Flux [587475ba] log:
     ├─possible versions are: 0.4.1-0.12.4 or uninstalled
     └─restricted to versions 0.12.4 by an explicit requirement, leaving only versions 0.12.4
```

which resulted in the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow one of those other packages listed above was causing the Flux version to be upper bounded at `v0.8.3` (I am guessing `Conda` but am not sure). By removing all the packages besides `IJulia`, I was able to do an `up Flux` and have it go to `[587475ba] ↑ Flux v0.8.3 ⇒ v0.12.4`.

Comment: does that mean all the packages must be reinstalled again from scratch?

Comment: In my case, yes, I removed them all besides IJulia